# dplyr concatenate strings by group - row by row

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to concatenate strings by group in the dplyr, but the resulting column should account only for the previous columns, not the leading ones

I want my data to look like this:

| ID | message | messages_used |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 53 | 53 |
| 1 | 54 | 53,54 |
| 1 | 55 | 53,54,55 |
| 2 | 53 | 53 |
| 2 | 58 | 53,58 |

Is it achievable using `dplyr` only?

Comment: If ID 1 has 3 rows and its third value is 55, what is the expected output? `54,55` or `53,54,55`?

Comment: @DarrenTsai It should contain all previous values, thus 53,54,55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Reduce(..., accumulate = TRUE)` from `base`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(messages_used = Reduce(\(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = ", "), message, accumulate = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#      ID message messages_used
#   <int>   <int> <chr>
# 1     1      53 53
# 2     1      54 53, 54
# 3     1      55 53, 54, 55
# 4     2      53 53
# 5     2      58 53, 58
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr::group_by()` and `purrr::accumulate()`:

```r
dat <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2), message = c(53,54,55,53,58))

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(message_used = accumulate(message, ~ paste(.x, .y, sep =",")))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>      ID message message_used
#>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>       
#> 1     1      53 53          
#> 2     1      54 53,54       
#> 3     1      55 53,54,55    
#> 4     2      53 53          
#> 5     2      58 53,58
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I think `toString(.x .y)` is a bit simpler

Comment: @GuedesBF: I think it needs to be  `toString(c(.x, .y))`, but its definitely another even shorter option. I leave the general version with `paste`, since it is more customizable.